# Nvidia Drivers for Asus K73SV-TY238V

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 13.10, graphics, asus

I have a 2 year old laptop (an ASUS K73SV, 8Gb RAM, intel i7-2630QM, nVIDIA GeForce GT540M 1Gb) and the GPU setup is a hybrid system (which means it switches between the intel HD integrated in the CPU).

I'm running only Ubuntu 13.10 atm and any proprietary driver installation of Nvidia has failed. Bumblebee, optimus, etc..

Is there anybody out there who can tell me if it's even possible to install proprietary drivers on my laptop? (or somebody with a similar setup who found a miraculous way to install and use them?).

I have been trying over a year to find something and this is my last resort ;).

Thank you for trying to help me!

EDIT: To clarify, before I installed the nvidia drivers without bumblebee, I just got stuck with a black screen at boot. I'd had to mess around with the command line to get everything working again but it did work again. Then I tried bumblebee, I thought it didn't work because nothing really changed (optirun). Now I have bumblebee installed but no idea how I should check if it works...

Comment: You should probably edit your question adding more details like what went wrong when you tried to install nvidia drivers and bumblebee. Have you followed the instructions here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

Comment: @GabrielF, I installed it yet again with this link you gave me (I did install this many times before), but I don't see anything that is changing. The optirun cmd seems like it does nothing, because my fps are completely the same with glxgears. Or is this a bad way of testing if bumblebee works?

Comment: Another interesting post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/366580/nvidia-740m-still-not-working-after-bumblebee-installation

Answer (score 0):

If you've followed the instructions [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation), you should probably have installed `bumblebee-nvidia` and `primus`, right? I believe primus gives a better performance over virtualgl. The latter is still the default, though, so you should run optirun with the `-b primus` option: `optirun -b primus glxgears`. See if you get a better performance.

Also, have a look on this post, which is very enlightening: https://askubuntu.com/a/36936/169250

EDIT: Try to update your nvidia drivers:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331
sudo apt-get --purge autoremove #this should remove old drivers
sudo apt-get reinstall bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

EDIT2: Apparently, you'll need to change a configuration file. See here (under **Updating Drivers**): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation

And it seems that running `optirun nvidia-settings` you can probably see if the nvidia GPU is working.

Comment: My performance is the same... This is really weird because I played TF2 on windows with max settings and now I have to set them to low just to get some decent gameplay. I guess it's just helpless.. This is never going to work

Comment: I believe nVidia GPU is not running... try updating the nvidia drivers. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I can't install the nvidia-331 driver, it says it conflicts with something else (and yes I did sudo apt-get update after adding the ppa ;)  ). This is what I got from the terminal (sorry it's in dutch but you could recognize the packages I guess):

Comment: gebruikt en sommige benodigde pakketten nog vastzitten in 'incoming'.
De volgende informatie helpt u mogelijk verder:

De volgende pakketten hebben niet-voldane vereisten:
 nvidia-304-updates : Conflicteert met: libopencl1
                      Conflicteert met: xorg-driver-binary
 nvidia-331 : Aanbevelingen: nvidia-settings-331 maar het zal niet geïnstalleerd worden
              Conflicteert met: libopencl1
              Conflicteert met: xorg-driver-binary
E: Fout, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve maakte scheidingen aan, dit kan veroorzaakt worden door vastgehouden pakketten.

Comment: Try removing older nvidia drivers (it seems nvidia-304-updates is installed): `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*`. I believe this will remove bumblebee-nvidia, so don't forget to install it along with nvidia-331 after that.

Comment: I did everything you said and it seemed to work (because of nvidia-settings not complaining it wasn't used). But after a reboot, X failed on my and my desktop manager (gnome) wouldn't boot. Although my login manager (lightDM) did... I purged everything (bumblebee, nvidia) by terminal and everything works again. I guess it's hopeless in this case.. But however, thank you for trying to help me! :)